# send "#" and "&" character through XML request

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

I need to send special character through XML request. to complete this action, I convert the string to UTF-8, as XML always use UTF-8 data encoding.[using below code]

```
byte[] myBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(MyMessage);
               MyMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myBytes);
```

I am able to send all the special characters like "!@$%^*()<>?" except "#" and "&". But those two character in very vital for me to send. how can I send those two character through XML.
I also try to replace and send using

```
MyMessage= MyMessage.Replace("&", "&#38;");  
MyMessage= MyMessage.Replace("#", "&#35;");
```

but it also doesn't work.

I have to create a request and send to a URL: sample requesting format is below:

```
http://1.2.3.4/Default.aspx?MSG_ID=20140107032647101768&BODY=test#&Time=20140107032647102769
```

Comment: If you form your `MyMessage` with a real xml parser you don't need to do anything special. It can escape all necessary chars. How do your form your xml? show its code.

Comment: Did you try using <![CDATA[]]>

Comment: Check out `SecurityElement.Escape` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Matthew wouldn't it escape all xml tags. Just post it as an answer so that I can downvote it.

Comment: Do you create your document by string concatenation? On an XMLDocument, it should work by assigning the string to a textnode.

Comment: @ThomasW. of course OP  does so....

Comment: SecurityElement.Escape gives same error.

Comment: From the description it looks more like a URL issue. How about & `%26` and # `%23`?

Comment: @spojsm: cdata gives same result. all special character send except # and &

Comment: @riad you still haven't posted the code about how formed your xml.

Comment: why i am (-) voted? it's a real problematic issue and no where have any solution . who is giving me (-) vote, please give me a solution.

Comment: @riad stop complaining and post a real question. Read the comments and see what people needs to answer your question.

Comment: @L.B Since when is # an xml tag?

Comment: @Matthew then post an answer. I will explain my reasoning in its comments:)

Comment: @L.B This is a website for professionals, try to act like one.  The reason I suggested they look into `SecurityElement.Escape` as the question looked relating to formatting an XML string, not a URL.

Comment: @Matthew the professional, I say the same it will escape the `<` and `>` s of xml. (Also a link for `This is a website for professionals` would be good.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace & by `%26` and # by `%23`.

This is not XML specific, it's a URL issue. To catch all issuey, try [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)